# Postgres retrieve name of a constraint

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, alter-table

How can I check the name of my constraint?

For instance:

```
ALTER TABLE contractor_contractor ADD CONSTRAINT commerce_contractor_pkey  PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

When I try to describe my table with `\d` I don't see any info about my primary key.

Comment: Looks like you're in psql, but pgadmin3 will show them to you by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the constraint name from the information schema:

```
SELECT constraint_name
FROM   information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE  table_catalog = 'my_catalog_name' AND    -- Database name
       table_schema = 'my_schema_name' AND      -- Often "public"
       table_name = 'contractor_contractor' AND 
       constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY';
```

Also note that newer version of plsql do provide information on primary keys under the indexes section. E.g.:

```
db=> CREATE TABLE contractor_contractor (id INT);
CREATE TABLE
db=> ALTER TABLE contractor_contractor
db-> ADD CONSTRAINT commerce_contractor_pkey  PRIMARY KEY(id);
ALTER TABLE
db=> \d contractor_contractor 
Table "public.contractor_contractor"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 id     | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "commerce_contractor_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the name of the index and the name of the constraint are not necessarily the same (though this will usually be the case)

Comment: The same table name can appear in multiple schemas in a single database.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' good point. Added a condition on the `table_catalog` column to address that.